# Handling electrical inside a galvanized pipe gazebo

Tags: electrical, grounding

I am constructing a gazebo on my flat roof deck out of 2" galvanized metal pipes and joints. I would like to attach a light fixture on one of the upper pipes. Can I pull electrical through the galvanized structure itself treating it as a large conduit? If so, at any point do I need to attach grounding screws or take any other measure to ensure I am following proper electrical practices? I am obtaining power through a plastic conduit protruding out of the roof which will feed directly in through the bottom of one of the riser posts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe to be correct to code you would have to run conduit inside the pipe. Might be a job for "smurf tube" or NM conduit (flexible corrugated plastic.) Pipe is not suited to run wires in, and may damage them. If constructing a metal frame on your roof, you should definitely bond it to ground, as it's going to look like a lighting rod, but that bond should be done in a manner suitable to lighting rods, down the outside of the building, not attached to your inside wiring directly.

Comment: Liquid tight flexible conduit or armored cable are sometimes run this way, depending whether indoor or out.

Answer (score 1):

It is not legal to use standard pipe as a wireway.

Standard pipe has a ridge that can cut the insulation.
If another code compliant wire way like flex is run inside the larger pipe that is code compliant (I use metal clad or MC cables in cases like this).

Any metal parts that may become energized require grounding so yes this framework with power will require grounding.